# JavaScript/jQuery validation for text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a texbox that is like this:

```
<input type="text" size="30" name="form[id]" id="form_id">
```

I need a JavaScript function that will validate:

1. No Spaces allowed.
2. Only numbers, letters, dashes(-) and underscores(_) allowed and no other special character allowed.
3. Shouldn't be empty

On Submit when the user's input is violating a validation. An alert message should be displayed.

Comment: You should learn about RegEx

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? This platform is not a place for free scripts...

Comment: Is this a joke? This is not Odesk or something... Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: StackOverflow != Freelancer.com

Comment: I am a ruby on rails/python developer, I do validations through models from the framework and I don't know client side validations. If you guys had helped rather then complaining it would have been appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function NoSpecialChars(){
    var element=document.getElementById('form_id');
    var specialchars= "!@#$%^&*()+=[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?";
    if(element.value.length==0){
        alert('Enter some text');
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < element.value.length; i++) {
        if (specialchars.indexOf(document.formname.fieldname.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
            alert ("Those are not allowed.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

You need to subscribe the onclientclick event of the textbox.

```
<input type="text" size="30" name="form[id]" id="form_id" onclientclick="return NoSpecialChars();">
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery I'll do something like that :

```
$('#formId').submit(function(e) {
    var validator = new RegExp(/^[\w_-]{1,}$/), //Min 1 char or more
        text = $('input[name="form[id]"]').val();
    if(validator.test(text))
        $(this).submit();
    else {
        alert('Code not valid');
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Regular Expressions Cheat Sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)

NB : jsfiddle is down atm, code hasn't been tested

Comment: Next time please request Google for such a script there must be many examples.

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery Validation Engine for Validating the Form..
Here is the Link for [JQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)